reactjs web-page loading time is about 13s because of mathjax
Hi I'm using a lot of math formula (almost 98% of my web site) in my react-js website, I'm using mathjax-better-react, it is slowing down significantly loading time, I tried to reduce significantly the web-page size by limiting the size of each component but still have the problem, besides the node-module folder increases significantly.
I also noticed one thing (I m not sur !), when I clear the cach the loading time seems to improve..
import { MathJax, MathJaxContext } from "better-react-mathjax";

const MeasureFunctions = () => {

return (
   <div className="ddd">
         <MathJaxContext>
              
              <MathJax inline>
                    A.3 Uniqueness and extension of measures A.3.1 Uniqueness of 
                    2). <MathJax inline>{" \( \Longleftarrow   \) "}
             </MathJax>:
       
        </MathJaxContext>
</div>

        );
};

export default MeasureFunctions;

